# Why does my MATLAB calculation/simulation differ greatly from my LTspice simulation?

Tags: transfer-function, feedback, matlab

Here is my circuit in LTspice.

[image]

The frequency AC is here:

[image]

This is DC with `.op` command.
--- MOSFET Transistors ---
Name:          m1
Model:       nmos-sh
Id:          1.91e-04
Vgs:         7.96e-01
Vds:         9.03e-01
Vbs:         0.00e+00
Vth:         4.00e-01
Vdsat:       3.96e-01
Gm:          9.61e-04
Gds:         1.75e-05
Gmb:         0.00e+00
Cbd:         0.00e+00
Cbs:         0.00e+00
Cgsov:       0.00e+00
Cgdov:       0.00e+00
Cgbov:       0.00e+00
Cgs:         0.00e+00
Cgd:         0.00e+00
Cgb:         0.00e+00

The following code is to calculate gain in MATLAB:

```
clearvars
syms Vin Vx Vout RS RF RD g_m ro Cgs Cgd s


eq1 = (Vin - Vx) / RS == (Vx - Vout) / RF + (Vx - Vout) * s * Cgd + Vx * s * Cgs;
eq2 = (Vx - Vout)/ RF + (Vx - Vout) * s * Cgd - Vout/RD == Vx * g_m + Vout / ro;

sol_out = solve([eq1, eq2], [Vout, Vx]);

Av= sol_out.Vout / Vin
```

$$
\frac{R_{D}r_{o}-R_{D}R_{F}g_{m}r_{o}+C_{\mathrm{gd}}R_{D}R_{F}r_{o}s}{R_{D}R_{F}+R_{D}R_{S}+R_{F}r_{o}+R_{D}r_{o}+R_{S}r_{o}+R_{D}R_{S}g_{m}r_{o}+C_{\mathrm{gd}}R_{D}R_{F}R_{S}s+C_{\mathrm{gs}}R_{D}R_{F}R_{S}s+C_{\mathrm{gd}}R_{D}R_{F}r_{o}s+C_{\mathrm{gd}}R_{F}R_{S}r_{o}s+C_{\mathrm{gs}}R_{F}R_{S}r_{o}s+C_{\mathrm{gs}}R_{D}R_{S}r_{o}s+C_{\mathrm{gd}}R_{D}R_{F}R_{S}g_{m}r_{o}s+C_{\mathrm{gd}}C_{\mathrm{gs}}R_{D}R_{F}R_{S}r_{o}s^{2}}
$$

When \$R_S\$ is 1 kΩ.

Here is the code:

```
clearvars
Cgd = 3.58*10^(-15);
Cgs = 7.11*10^(-14);
ro = 1/(1.75*10^(-5));

RF = 10^3;
RS = 10^3;
RD = 10^3;
g_m = 9.61*10^(-4);

zeros = (- 1 + RF*g_m)/(Cgd*RF);
f_zero = zeros/(2*pi)

p1 = -(Cgd*RD*RF*RS - (Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2 + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2 + Cgs^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS*ro + 2*Cgd^2*RD*RF^2*RS^2*ro - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF^2*RS*ro + 4*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF^2*RS^2*ro - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF*RS^2*ro + 2*Cgs^2*RD*RF^2*RS^2*ro + 2*Cgs^2*RD^2*RF*RS^2*ro + Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*ro^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD*RF^2*RS*ro^2 + Cgd^2*RF^2*RS^2*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF^2*RS*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF*RS*ro^2 + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RF^2*RS^2*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF*RS^2*ro^2 + Cgs^2*RF^2*RS^2*ro^2 + 2*Cgs^2*RD*RF*RS^2*ro^2 + Cgs^2*RD^2*RS^2*ro^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro + 2*Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS*g_m*ro^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro^2 + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF*RS^2*g_m*ro^2 + Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2*g_m^2*ro^2)^(1/2) + Cgs*RD*RF*RS + Cgd*RD*RF*ro + Cgs*RD*RS*ro + Cgd*RF*RS*ro + Cgs*RF*RS*ro + Cgd*RD*RF*RS*g_m*ro)/(2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF*RS*ro);
f_p1 = p1/(2*pi)

p2 = -((Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2 + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2 + Cgs^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS*ro + 2*Cgd^2*RD*RF^2*RS^2*ro - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF^2*RS*ro + 4*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF^2*RS^2*ro - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF*RS^2*ro + 2*Cgs^2*RD*RF^2*RS^2*ro + 2*Cgs^2*RD^2*RF*RS^2*ro + Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*ro^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD*RF^2*RS*ro^2 + Cgd^2*RF^2*RS^2*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF^2*RS*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF*RS*ro^2 + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RF^2*RS^2*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF*RS^2*ro^2 + Cgs^2*RF^2*RS^2*ro^2 + 2*Cgs^2*RD*RF*RS^2*ro^2 + Cgs^2*RD^2*RS^2*ro^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro + 2*Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS*g_m*ro^2 + 2*Cgd^2*RD*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro^2 + 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF^2*RS^2*g_m*ro^2 - 2*Cgd*Cgs*RD^2*RF*RS^2*g_m*ro^2 + Cgd^2*RD^2*RF^2*RS^2*g_m^2*ro^2)^(1/2) + Cgd*RD*RF*RS + Cgs*RD*RF*RS + Cgd*RD*RF*ro + Cgs*RD*RS*ro + Cgd*RF*RS*ro + Cgs*RF*RS*ro + Cgd*RD*RF*RS*g_m*ro)/(2*Cgd*Cgs*RD*RF*RS*ro);
f_p2 = p2/(2*pi)
```

The results are the following:

f_zero =

-1.7338e+09

f_p1 =

-4.3206e+09

f_p2 =

-9.2038e+10

However, the zero frequency is 2.1146314 GHz (3 dB). pole 1 is 3.225216 GHz (3 dB) and pole 2 is 99.366294 GHz (3 dB) measured in SPICE.

The following are the measurement in SPICE.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have created my MATLAB graph for this SPICE.

[image]

The following is SPICE asc file.

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 64 -80 -80 -80
WIRE 320 -80 64 -80
WIRE -80 -64 -80 -80
WIRE -80 32 -80 16
WIRE -80 32 -240 32
WIRE -240 48 -240 32
WIRE -80 64 -80 32
WIRE -16 64 -80 64
WIRE -80 80 -80 64
WIRE -80 80 -96 80
WIRE -80 96 -80 80
WIRE -16 96 -80 96
WIRE -208 112 -240 112
WIRE -80 112 -80 96
WIRE -16 160 -80 160
WIRE 480 160 480 112
WIRE 640 160 640 112
WIRE -320 192 -368 192
WIRE -288 192 -320 192
WIRE -208 192 -208 112
WIRE -176 192 -176 80
WIRE -176 192 -208 192
WIRE -128 192 -176 192
WIRE 320 192 320 -80
WIRE -176 272 -176 256
WIRE -176 272 -368 272
WIRE -80 272 -80 208
WIRE -80 272 -176 272
WIRE -16 272 -16 160
WIRE -16 272 -80 272
WIRE 320 272 -16 272
WIRE 480 272 480 240
WIRE 480 272 320 272
WIRE 640 272 640 240
WIRE 640 272 480 272
WIRE -368 288 -368 272
FLAG -368 288 0
FLAG 64 -80 VDD
FLAG -176 192 VG
FLAG -16 64 VO
IOPIN -16 64 Out
FLAG 480 112 Vicm
FLAG 640 112 Vid
FLAG -320 192 VIN
SYMBOL nmos4 -128 112 R0
WINDOW 3 56 60 Left 2
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=12.35u ad=6.2p as=6.2p pd=13.4u ps=13.4u
SYMBOL voltage 320 176 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VDD
SYMATTR Value 1.2
SYMBOL voltage 480 144 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vicm
SYMATTR Value 0.69
SYMBOL voltage 640 144 R0
WINDOW 3 24 152 Left 2
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName Vid
SYMBOL bv -368 176 R0
WINDOW 0 -60 23 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName VIN1
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vicm)+V(Vid)
SYMBOL res -80 64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rf1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res -96 -80 R0
SYMATTR InstName RD
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res -192 176 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName RS
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL cap -192 192 R0
WINDOW 0 39 29 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName Cgs
SYMATTR Value 7.11e-14
SYMBOL cap -256 48 R0
WINDOW 3 -61 49 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 3.58e-15
SYMATTR InstName Cgdov
TEXT -496 -216 Left 2 !.MODEL PMOS-SH pmos(kp=45u,vto=-0.42, lambda = {0.14/1}, gamma = 0)
TEXT -496 -160 Left 2 !.MODEL NMOS-SH nmos(kp=180u,vto=0.4, lambda = {0.1/1}, gamma = 0)
TEXT -464 -248 Left 2 ;M1:  l=1u w=12.35u ad=6.2p as=6.2p pd=13.4u ps=13.4u
TEXT -408 -24 Left 2 !.op\n.ac oct 10 100Meg 1T
TEXT -400 -72 Left 2 !;tf V(VO) Vid
TEXT -400 -136 Left 2 !;dc VDD 0 1.8 0.01
TEXT 392 -88 Left 2 !.param Rf =1e2
TEXT 392 -64 Left 2 !.step param Rf list 1e2 1e3 1e4
```

Comment: How come the passband gain is so low?

Comment: @Andyaka Can you simulate in your computer?

Comment: I don't need to. Experience tells me it will be minus 3 to 6 dB. Have you got the input voltage set up to be 1 volts in AC analysis?

Comment: @Andyaka I believe it’s low because the MOSFET is ON in this simulation.

Comment: The simulation doesn't appear to differ "greatly" to me. How did you measure them? Are you sure that you measured poles and zeros correctly in LTspice? The first zero and pole are quite close to each other, so I doubt you measured them correctly.

Comment: @internet Can you have a look at my measurement? I have updated my question now

Comment: @kile The pole and the zero are close to each other (within a decade or so) and influence each other, so you can't rely on the 3 dB point.

Comment: What should I rely on if 3 dB point is not ok?

Comment: Why don't you plot the MATLAB equation for voltage gain in LTspice and overlay it with the simulation to verify if they match?

Comment: @internet I have plotted the matlab picture. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @kile They look very similar, but why don't you export the LTSpice curve and plot them in MATLAB on the same figure to verify if they match?